# How to change webpart title background for only 1 webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, jquery, css, html

I have three webparts and each of these have titles. 
I want to change the background of a **single** title.

I have the following webparts: 
[image]

I want to change title background for only this Title called `Aplikacionet` but I do not want to style other webpart titles like `CleverTools` or `Internal Links`.

The webpart title I would like, is this:

[image]

Comment: Find the `id` by inspecting element from browser and then apply some **CSS**

Comment: Thanks @AtishDipongkor for your suggestion, but when I modify the the background with my webpart id the background is too large i want it to be smaller but i cant do it with CSS i dont know how!

Comment: Can you show your code? I mean update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find `id` of that WP. Something like `WebPartTitleWPQ4`.
Edit that page and insert script editor WP and add `<style>`

```
<style>
#WebPartTitleWPQ4 h2 {
    background-color: #000; 
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

**EDIT**
Find where is title. For ex.

```
<style>
#WebPartTitleWPQ4 h2 {
    background-color: #000; 
    }
#WebPartTitleWPQ4 h2 span {
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

Comment: but the color: #fff won`t work for me! why?

Comment: Try with color: #fff !important

Comment: nope it won`t work

Comment: now it is working thank you so much u r a live saver