# Change style of web part tile

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part

Is it possible to change the title style of the web parts titles? 
If yes and if I have to change some coding, how do I access the files?
I am using the latest version of Sharepoint (16.0 I think)
Thank you in advance

Comment: The latest version of SP on-premises is 2019. Do you use classic mode or modern experience?

Answer (score 0):

To change style of web part title, find the id by inspecting element from browser and then apply some CSS.

Similar issue posts for your reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/45223c5e-d75c-482c-9584-56bb133c6907/sharepoint-2013-coloring-the-web-part-title-background-and-changing-font-color?forum=sharepointdevelopment

[How to change webpart title background for only 1 webpart?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166849/how-to-change-webpart-title-background-for-only-1-webpart/166853)